# Python script run in background not writing to file?

Tags: background-process, python-3.x

I've created my first ever python script and it works fine in the foreground, but when I run it in the background it creates, but fails to write anything to the file. I run the script with command : python -u testit.py &
Please help me understand why this happens.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
dtLog = dt.strftime("ThermoLogs/TempLOG%Y%m%d")
f = open(dtLog,"a")
while True:
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    print('{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(dt))
    f.write('{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(dt))
    f.write('\n')
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output will arrive in bursts (it is being buffered). With the sleep set to `0.01` I am getting bursts about every 2 seconds. So for a delay of `5` you will get them much less frequent. You may also note that it outputs all pending outputs when you terminate it.

To make the output arrive now call `f.flush()`.

I don't see any difference between foreground and background. However it should not buffer stdout when going to a terminal.

Comment: Thank you!  f.flush() did the trick.  Perhaps it was because I use Kill to stop the process? I thought the -u option when calling it would cause it not to buffer the output and stdout seemed to work fine as the print was written to the screen and with nohup to the nohup.out file OK, but for whatever reason, without the f.flush() it never made it to the intended file.